# my AngularJS route is not working

Tags: angularjs, routes, ngroute

I'm trying to use angularJS ng-route but I'm not able to make it work.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="table-bordered" ng-repeat="my in mines">
                    <td>{{my.ID}}</td>
                    <td>{{my.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{my.Type}}</td>
                    <td><a href="#/edit/{{my.ID}}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


            <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp', [
        'ngRoute'
    ])
        .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
         .when('edit/:ID', {
             templateUrl: 'edit.html',
             controller: 'myController'
         })


    }]);
})();
```

I understand that Angular should replace the content of the `ng-view div` with the `edit.html` content (only a hello world text for the moment) but the browser is redirecting me to an inexisting page (localhost/edit/ID)

What did I do wrongly?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to comments I'm no more redirected to a wrong page but the `ng-view div` is not replaced/filled.

Comment: Should be `href="#/edit/{{my.ID}}"`

Comment: add `#` to your href `href="#/edit/{{my.ID}}"`

Comment: It is not solving the issue.. In the angular doc about routing (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example) There is no #

Comment: HTML5Mode is false by default, you can avoid use of the hash if you turn it on with $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

Comment: ok thanks for feedback, I activated html5, now it is no more redirecting but still not filling ng-view :-(

Comment: can't  enable html5Mode if you don't also configure server

Comment: finally I deactivated HTML5 but added # in the href for editing